# How to use Column Value as header in Query in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I was trying use query to show results as below.  But I couldn't figure out how to use Column A (months) as a header.

I knew how to use Vlook or Filter function to generate same results.   Since my data is huge, I prefer to use Query function to keep my data flexible. Thank you for helping.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljrMdM4m0YT35EP7HxY-Gdj9SrEv6DHoQw_qL8Z9c-Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, needs tweaking with ordering though.

```
=query(Sheet1!A1:C71,"select B, sum(C) group by B pivot A")
```

Comment: Hi, I do need your help to with ordering.  is it possible to show the data by Column A Descending.   Thank you so much

Comment: I added it to your sheet. Basically `transpose` the query result so row 1 becomes a column, then `sort` by that, then `transpose` it back. Query, as far as I know, can only sort rows, unfortunately, with  `order by` .

Comment: Thank you,  That's what I was looking for.    Could you also format date as "Aug-2022" instead of  '2022-8-1' ?

Comment: Now that might be an issue. `query`'s `format` works on columns, so it is again not usable, but there aren't other functions for this either. I suggest using this table as an intermediary, and creating the final table with the data from this, then you can take the values from that first row and convert them to date values.